# How to get the mean for each group in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Here's my data:

```
  v        x
  0:0       96
  0:0      119
  0:0      108
  1:0       73
  1:0       65
  2:0       83
  2:0       73
  2:0       23
```

How can I get the mean by groups of v i.e. the mean of x for all 0:0s, 1:0 etc.

My failed attempt:

```
df = read.csv(input.file.path, header=TRUE)
df$v <- as.factor(df$v)
ave(df$x, df$v)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried this? Did you get an error message?

Comment: `ave(df$x, df$v)` works fine for me, It gives `107.66667 107.66667 107.66667  69.00000  69.00000  59.66667  59.66667  59.66667` as result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ave` isn't the best option here. It will return a vector the same length as your inputs, while I'm guessing that you want to lump the results together into a more compact table.

If that's the case, try `aggregate` or `tapply` instead:

```
> aggregate(x ~ v, df, mean)
    v         x
1 0:0 107.66667
2 1:0  69.00000
3 2:0  59.66667

> tapply(df$x, df$v, mean)
      0:0       1:0       2:0 
107.66667  69.00000  59.66667
```

Comment: Or `by()`, which is a wrapper for `tapply()`, and which I personally find easier to read in code: calculate something *by* groups.

Comment: To see it in one line like that makes my heart sink after hours of attempts. It worked perfectly. I later split v into two columns and used: df <- aggregate(x ~ v1+v2, df, mean). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @PhloxMidas, don't let your heart sink over that! There are honestly *many* grouping functions in R, both in base R and with the many packages available, and it can be hard to sometimes hit upon which one you really need until you start exploring the features of each more in depth.